# can mootools and jquery coexist together?

Tags: jquery, mootools

i have a website that uses mootools and i want to add a jquery plugin to create a chat like FB. before that, i want to know if mootools an jquery can coexist together or is better to have them in different pages.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. True most answers (as the one below) is incorrect, but still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer would be yes.

The longer one is that you have to tell jQuery not to use the $ as a function name. This can be done with

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

More on this [here](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-mootools).

Comment: that's pretty pointless anyway, if you load jquery first and have mootools greater than 1.2.3, it won't assign $ and revert to `document.id` instead anyway.